# How to convert an argument of a function into a string to put it into a string?

Tags: javascript

i have this hypothetical function:

```
function Introduction(name, adj) {
    return "My name is " + name + " and i am " + adj;
  };

console.log(Introduction(Mark, bad));
```

And its always say: Mark is not defined

I tried the String-Method:

```
function Introduction(name, adj) {
    return "My name is " + String(name) + " and i am " + String(adj);
  };

console.log(Introduction(Mark, bad));
```

I tried the toString-Method:

```
function Introduction(name, adj) {
    return "My name is " + name.toString() + " and i am " + adj.toString();
  };

console.log(Introduction(Mark, bad));
```

Its only working if i write the arguments as a string:

```
console.log(Introduction("Mark", "bad"));
```

Why? Is there no way, to write a function like this, where i dont have to use already strings as arguments? Or only in a very complicated way, to transform first the arguments into a string and then use them to build a text?

I tried it with this:

```
function Introduction(name, adj) {
    var name2 = String(name);
    var adj2 = String(adj);
    return "My name is " + name2 + " and i am " + adj2;
  };

console.log(Introduction(Mark, bad));
```

But this isnt working either ? There is always a ReferenceError, that Mark is not defined.

Comment: Hey man what are doing its insane use `console.log(Introduction("mark" ,  "bad"))`

Comment: `Mark is not defined` means a variable named`Mark` is not defined. You can create a variable as `const Mark = "Mark"`

Comment: Just write `const Mark = 'Joseph', bad = 'ok';`, then `console.log(Introduction(Mark, bad));` will work. Yes, you must pass a string, and Yes, it must be a string literal if you don't mean to use a variable. It is not complicated but necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there no way, to write a function like this, where i dont have to use already strings as arguments? Or only in a very complicated way, to transform first the arguments into a string and then use them to build a text?

No, there isn't. At least not inside the JavaScript program itself.

`Introduction(Mark, bad)` means "Pass the values of the variables `Mark` and the variable `bad`".

You get an error because they don't exist.

There is no way to change what that syntax means in JavaScript. It's how the language works at a very basic syntax level.

If you want a string then you need to have something that JavaScript recognises as a string such as:

- A variable you have defined and assigned a string to
- A string literal
- A call to a function that returns a string

---

Earlier I said "At least not inside the JavaScript program itself.". So if we remove that requirement…

You could design your own programming language where those tokens meant different things, then write a compiler to convert your programming language into JavaScript.

This is how [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) converts code written into newer versions of JS into older versions of JS for running on older JS engines.

Answer (score -1):

Well you can do this by creating variables prior the function declaration, and referencing these variables in the call of the function like in this code:

```
let Mark= "Mark";
let bad= "bad";

function Introduction(name, adj) {
    return "My name is " + name+ " and i am " + adj;
  };

console.log(Introduction(Mark, bad));
```

Little additional tip in js, you can use `` instead of "" or '' to initiate and close a string, which allows you to directly reference a variable with the following syntax:

```
let Mark= "Mark";
let bad = "bad";

function Introduction(name, adj) {
    return `My name is ${name} and i am ${adj}`;
  };

console.log(Introduction(Mark, bad));
```

I personnaly find it more readable.

Hope I answered your question.